# Multi-Dimensional Array Index Out of Bounds Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need help with figuring out what exactly is wrong with this code:

```
public class Fibonacci
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[][] numbers;
        numbers = new int[1][25];
        numbers[0][0] = 0;
        numbers[0][1] = 1;
        System.out.println("Fibonacci series: \n");
        System.out.println(numbers[0][0]);
        System.out.println(numbers[0][1]);

        for(int i=2; i < 20; i++)
        {
            numbers[1][i] = numbers[0][i-2] + numbers[0][i-1];
            System.out.println(numbers[1][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at Fibonacci.main(Fibonacci.java:15)
```

I can see that my array index is out of bounds on line 15, but I don't know how to fix it. :/
Help appreciated. :)
P.S. New here

Comment: numbers[1][i] should be numbers[0][i]? You only have 1 row, remember?

Comment: There is also no need to have a two dimensional array in your example. Simply remove the first useless dimension.

Comment: Ahhhh thanks. :) And i do need the 2 dimensions because this is my school's idea of a practice activity.

Comment: Yes, everyone needs to practice using the wrong design to solve a problem.  Builds character, or something.  Seriously, I wonder whether the person who came up with this activity thought it through.

Answer (score 4):

You have `numbers[1][i]` both in lines 15 and 16, but that throws an exception because the size of the first dimension is only 1. Try changing both to `numbers[0][i]`.

Or, from what it looks like you're trying to do you can alter your initialization of your array to

```
numbers = new int[2][25];
```

Comment: Note that if you really want two rows, other changes will have to be made to the code.  The code as written will not display the sequence properly if just the `new int` is changed.

Answer (score 0):

In short, your array is not big enough.

You declare your array as "new int[1][25]", which means, because of [1], only a single row.
But then on line 15 you reference the second row: "numbers[1][i]".

There is clearly more wrong with your code based on your class name of Fibonacci, but the solution to your immediate problem is to make your array larger: "new int[X][25]" but put in something bigger for X.

Answer (score 0):

The two dimensinal array is `numbers = new int[1][25];` first dimension size is 1 , it mean you can access the element or set the value using index `0`.So change the code from  `numbers[1][i]` to  `numbers[0][i]`